# Swift - Display assertion failures inline in Xcode like XCTest failures?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I'd like to write some custom test assertion types and have them be displayed in Xcode, similarly to how the XCTAssert() failures are displayed:

[image]

Is there a way for me to hook into Xcode and make this happen?

I want my own assertion function to show its error inline the same way here:

[image]

The best resource I've found so far is Apple's XCTest [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest), but I haven't been able to understand if that even includes the logic that is responsible for displaying the error UI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to call `XCTFail()` from your custom assertion, but pass along the file name and line number of the call site. For example:

```
func verify(myThing: MyThing, file: StaticString = #filePath, line: UInt = #line) {
   // Do your verification. Then when you want to fail the test,
   XCTFail("Some message about \(myThing)", file: file, line: line)
}
```

At the call site, you'd let the default arguments provide `file` and `line`. So it would just look like:

```
verify(myThing: thing)
```

In Swift, XCTest assertions are global functions. This means your helper can also be a global function, and shared across test suites without having to subclass `XCTestCase`.

Comment: `XCTFail` seems to be using `#filePath` instead of `#file`. It probably should be used as default parameter for verify as well.

Comment: Updated answer for Xcode 12. Thank you, @Daniel

Answer (score 5):

With `Xcode 12` we can inline assertion using [`XCTIssue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctissue)
and the existing `recordFailure` is deprecated.
Here is the example of test

```
import XCTest
@testable import TestAssertionForward

class TestAssertionForwardTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() throws {
        assert(actual: 10, expected: 20) // asserts in method
        assert(actual: 10, expected: 11) // asserts in method
        assertInLine(actual: 10, expected: 11) // asserts in line
        assertInLine(actual: 10, expected: 11) // asserts in line
    }
}

extension TestAssertionForwardTests {

    func assert(actual: Int, expected: Int) {
        XCTAssertEqual(actual, expected)
    }

    func assertInLine(actual: Int, expected: Int, filePath: String = #file, lineNumber: Int = #line) {
        if actual != expected {
            let location = XCTSourceCodeLocation(filePath: filePath, lineNumber: lineNumber)
            let context = XCTSourceCodeContext(location: location)
            let issue = XCTIssue(type: .assertionFailure,
                                 compactDescription: "\(actual) is not equal to \(expected)",
                                 detailedDescription: nil,
                                 sourceCodeContext: context,
                                 associatedError: nil,
                                 attachments: [])
            record(issue)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the failure assertions

[image]

Comment: Learn more from this wwdc session: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10687/

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do exactly what you want, I just managed to do it, like this:

## Use `recordFailure`

You can achieve what you want just by calling `recordFailure`, in any test (inheriting from standard `XCTestCase`).

## Shorter syntax

### Either extend `XCTestCase`

If you want to simplify the call to this function you either write an extension function wrapping it.

### or subclass

You can also subclass `XCTestCase` (which can be a good idea if you want to share some setup, being called in `setup`, then you only need to do it in this new superclass to your test classes).

```swift
class TestCase: XCTestCase {

  func forwardFailure(
        withDescription description: String = "Something went wrong",
        inFile filePath: String = #file,
        atLine line: Int = #line,
        expected: Bool = false
    ) {
        self.recordFailure(
            withDescription: description,
            inFile: filePath,
            atLine: line,
            expected: expected
        )
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how to use `expected: Bool`, it is a required argument for the [`recordFailure` method (source)](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/11b22e5ed8d6ffc2734810ae6d3b56160092745b/Sources/XCTest/Public/XCTestRun.swift#L121-L136), but looks like Apple mostly sets it to `false`.

## Custom assert methods

Now you can declare your custom assert methods, like this (or as an extension on just `XCTestCase`, depending on your choice):

```swift
extension TestCase {

    /// Since `Foobar.Type` does not conform to `Equatable`, even if `Foobar` conforms to `Equatable`, we are unable to write `XCTAssertEquals(type(of: foo), Foobar.self)`, this assert method fixes that.
    func XCTAssertType<Actual, Expected>(
        of actual: Actual,
        is expectedType: Expected.Type,

        _ filePath: String = #file,
        _ line: Int = #line
    ) {

        if let _ = actual as? Expected { return /* success */  }
        let actualType = Mirror(reflecting: actual).subjectType

        forwardFailure(
            withDescription: "Expected '\(actual)' to be of type '\(expectedType)', but was: '\(actualType)'",

            inFile: filePath,
            atLine: line
        )
    }

}
```

And now it reports the error, **not** inside the custom assert, but at call site .

## Using standard assert methods + forward location in file

You can also just forward the `line` of, and pass to standards asserts, if you look at e.g. `XCTAssertTrue`, it accepts a line argument, and a `file` argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 14**

A simple solution would be to pass in the `file` and `line` values from the call site into your custom test assertion, then use those values in the XCTAssert call:

Custom Test Assertion:

```
private func verify(_ input: String, formatsTo expectedFormat: String, file: StaticString = #filePath, line: UInt = #line) {
    let result = timeParser.formatTime(string: input)
    XCTAssertEqual(result, expectedFormat, file: file, line: line)
}
```

This will provide the same failure message as if you had called the assert locally:

[image]